# I'm trying to render an image but weird pixel glitches keep popping up? any help would be much aprreciated!

Tags: rendering

[image: Also when jsut basic rendering of a cube or mesh this happens?]I'm trying to render for example a very basic image of a cube but when i enter render mode little boxes appear making the picture grainy and hard to see, if anyone could help, thank you.[image: this is an example of what happens]

Comment: cycle render or evee? is GPU active?

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! Do you have a material on the cube? If so can you show it? Does this happen when rendering too, or just in the viewport? You can also attach blend files which can be very helpful too. Use this site if you choose to do that: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Sanbaldo the issue happens both in Evee and in Cycles and GPU is not active

Comment: Yes it does happen in render mode too i have just the material but if i try to put another one on the little blue and white squares will be on that as well

Comment: So i added a colour to one of my other designs that was having a similair problem and that seemed to fix it so idk.